# How to create "Copy" button?

Tags: javascript, flash

Ok say you have this:

```
<input id="test" value="" />
```

Value of that input is dynamicly generated.

Now a user can double click on that input to select value, ctrl+c to copy.

I also found that with javascript you can select value of input with "click".

But when it comes to creating a button that when clicked will copy value of that input into OS's clipboard - i have found only solutions that works with Flash.

Now i want to know how can i create that button with javascript? Ofc if it is possible... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering the implications (especially security concerns), copying to/from clipboard is not something that is quite allowed / easy.

Those questions / answsers might help you, about that :

- [How to Copy to Clipboard in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)
- [Is it possible to read the clipboard in firefox, safari and chrome using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233719/is-it-possible-to-read-the-clipboard-in-firefox-safari-and-chrome-using-javascri)

In each case, it seems that the solution is to use some little .swf file -- which means working with flash (maybe some old version of flash, actually)...

For instance, you could take a look at the [Zero Clipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard) library (yeap, flash...) :

> The Zero Clipboard library provides an
>   easy way to copy text to the clipboard
>   using an invisible Adobe Flash movie,
>   and a JavaScript interface. The "Zero"
>   signifies that the library is
>   invisible and the user interface is
>   left entirely up to you.
>
> This library is fully compatible with
>   Flash Player 10, which requires that
>   the clipboard copy operation be
>   initiated by a user click event inside
>   the Flash movie. This is achieved by
>   automatically floating the invisible
>   movie on top of a DOM element of your
>   choice.

In pure Javascript, it seems to be possible in Internet Explorer, but not in other browsers...

Comment: So it would seem... <_< t-up for answer, but i will wait some more before marking this as accepted answer... :)

Comment: @GaVrA : I'm curious about other answers too, actually ;-) ;; As a user who doesn't allow flash by default (I use the flashblock plugin for firefox), I don't like flash-based solutions ^^

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN i dont want to be so harsh, but i will say that i hate flash. So if it can be done without using it - kudos! :) Cant wait for HTML5...

Comment: @GaVrA : without going to something as strong as "hate", I quite understand what you mean ^^