# How to grab a column from a web browser

Tags: multiple-columns

In a .txt file, I can hold down the "Option" button and select one or more columns.

Is there an equivalent for grabbing column information on a web page?

I am currently copying-and-pasting the website material into a .txt file, and then started to wonder if that step could be eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but maybe this information will help anyways.

If you are just looking for a client tool, the following should be helpful (in chrome): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/columncopy/lapbbfoohlcmlbdaakldmmallcbcbpjb

If you are looking to add a copy button to a web page that will copy text maybe the following will help [How to create "Copy" button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383411/how-to-create-copy-button)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If it's data in an HTML `<table>` you can copy it and paste it into an Excel file. That should make it a lot easier to grab by columns.

Comment: Bill, thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, even with "Paste Special" the columns become too skewed. My column-of-interest is no longer in one column.

Comment: That sounds like bad HTML, not sure there's going to be a clean way to handle your situation without being able to get a closer look at it.