# Is it possible to read the clipboard contents in Chrome without an onPaste handler?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, chromium

Is it possible to read the clipboard without user interaction? Just like IE's `window.clipdData.getData("Text")`?

I've seen other questions, such as [*Is it possible to read the clipboard contents in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome using Javascript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233719/is-it-possible-to-read-the-clipboard-in-firefox-safari-and-chrome-using-javascri), but the onpaste event is not what we are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible due to privacy/safety reasons. You could sniff the clipboard in a loop and catch passwords copied elsewere.

( That password sniffing seems worth trying if it works in IE :D )