# How to read clipboard data in cross browser?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser, clipboard, paste

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Copy / Put text on the clipboard with FireFox, Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome)
>   [How to Copy to Clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)

Hi ,

scenario: I copied some content (either from notepad or word) and want to paste it in my iframe. On before pasting i want to manipulate the clipboard content.
In IE i can do it with `window.clipboardData.getData("Text");` 
How to read the clipboard data in other browsers (FF/chrome and safari)

Comment: @David, @Crowder: Both those questions are undoubtedly similar to this one but both concern putting data onto the clipboard rather than reading data from it.

Comment: @David, @Crowder: It is a possible duplicate of this question though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233719/is-it-possible-to-read-the-clipboard-in-firefox-safari-and-chrome-using-javascri

Comment: Jesus christ SO needs to moderate the mods so badly. Neither of the questions this was marked as a dupe of are the same question at ALL.

Answer (score 7):

You'll only be able to do this in most browsers when the user explicitly triggers a paste (for example, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> or the edit or context menus).

In Firefox and Opera you'll need to use a hack, such as the one I outlined here: [JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser/2177059#2177059).

In Internet Explorer, Safari and Chrome, you can access the clipboard directly during a paste using `window.clipboardData` in IE and the `paste` event's `clipboardData` property in WebKit. More information can be found on the [Apple developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/CopyAndPaste.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001234-176911).

Answer (score 5):

Incase of Firefox

> By default, JavaScript is not allowed
>   to read or set your clipboard data for
>   security and privacy reasons. This is
>   because websites scripts can erase and
>   replace what you currently have in
>   your clipboard (data loss issue) and
>   they can read whatever you have in
>   your clipboard (security and privacy
>   issue)
>
> [From Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard)

Comment: nowadays 
Document.execCommand('paste') [read there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)