# Get current clipboard content?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, paste

I'd like to know a way to make my script detect the content of the clipboard and paste it into a text field when the page is opened, with no input from the user. How can it be done?

Comment: You cannot really know what is in the clipboard of a user unless you used some sort of flash backend when they copied the text. ------- **Update:** [A more _correct_ answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413100/561731)

Comment: Please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233719/is-it-possible-to-read-the-clipboard-in-firefox-safari-and-chrome-using-javascri http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to read the clipboard in Firefox, Safari and Chrome using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233719/is-it-possible-to-read-the-clipboard-in-firefox-safari-and-chrome-using-javascri)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to read the clipboard in Firefox, Safari and Chrome using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233719/is-it-possible-to-read-the-clipboard-in-firefox-safari-and-chrome-using-javascr)

Answer (score 155):

Note that this solution does not work in Firefox as of version 109 / February 2023, so do not use this unless you know that none of your users use Firefox.

Use the [new clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API), via `navigator.clipboard`. It can be used like this:

With async/await syntax:

```
const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
```

Or with Promise syntax:

```
navigator.clipboard.readText()
  .then(text => {
    console.log('Pasted content: ', text);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
  });
```

Keep in mind that this will prompt the user with a permission request dialog box, so no funny business possible.

The above code will not work if called from the console. It only works when you run the code in an active tab. To run the code from your console you can set a timeout and click in the website window quickly:

```
setTimeout(async () => {
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  console.log(text);
}, 2000);
```

Read more on the API and usage in the [Google developer docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi).

[Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#async-clipboard-api)

Comment: Note that it always results in error when called from console. But it _does_ work on a direct user action, like when you press a button on the page.

Comment: this seems to only return plain text... even when rich text is on the clipboard. how can i get that?\

Comment: @Michael, support for images and others was just added in the last Chrome version (76)

Comment: You can test in the console by wrapping in a `setTimeout`, then clicking back on the page.

Comment: That doesn't work in Firefox at all.

Comment: +10000 for `Keep in mind that this will prompt the user with a permission request dialog box, so no funny business possible.`  I literally started thinking of lots of funny business 

Answer (score 80):

`window.clipboardData.getData('Text')` will work in some browsers.  However, many browsers where it does work will prompt the user as to whether or not they wish the web page to have access to the clipboard.

Comment: Will this work in any browser other than Internet Explorer?

Comment: Probably not.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: You can check compatibility here http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboardData

Comment: A better solution is get by the node object, but don't by window object. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData)

Comment: I am worried about Keepass and its security. The app lets me copy my passwords to the clipboard.

Answer (score 19):

You can use

```
window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
```

to get the content of user's clipboard in IE. However, in other browser you may need to use flash to get the content, since there is no standard interface to access the clipboard. May be you can have try this plugin [Zero Clipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard)

Comment: link is working fine (again)

Comment: ZeroClipboard only allows you to copy *to* the clipboard, not read *from* it.

Answer (score 7):

Following will give you the selected content as well as updating the clipboard.

Bind the element id with a copy event and then get the selected text. You can replace or modify the text. Get the clipboard and set the new text. To get the exact formatting you need to set the type as "text/html". You may also bind it to the document instead of element.

```js
document.querySelector('element').bind('copy', function(event) {
  var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString(); 
  selectedText = selectedText.replace(/\u200B/g, "");

  clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
  clipboardData.setData('text/html', selectedText);

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to this site! I'm glad that you are contributing by answering on a question. But please be aware that your answer does not really answer the OP's question. The question is *retrieving* content from the clipboard and paste it somewhere when opening a page. Also, since the question does not have a [tag:jquery] tag, answers with jQuery should contain a note that a library (jQuery) is used.

Comment: This is to select a data from a webpage and set it to the clipboard, the question is to pull the clipboard data (it can be from any source) so we should be able to get the data from the clipboard no matter from where it's copied.