# Find out what was copied in a PDF file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

Been googling around for this but nothing fits my case.

Suppose there's a PDF embedded in my webapp. User highlights and copies a line. I want to know when that happens and what the contents of the copy were.

Assume that my users will use whatever browser I tell them to and will give me permissions to do this.

Apologies if there is an answer - I found a bunch of stuff around copying clipboard data, and firing copy events when Cmd/Ctrl + C was pressed, but none gave me the contents of the copy on a PDF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current clipboard content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content)

Comment: Why is copying clipboard data not an acceptable solution?