# Simulate keypress (ctrl+v) and send the KeyboardEvent to a div in Angular2 or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a div:

```
<div class="paste-area-content"
  #pasteDiv contenteditable="true" 
  (paste)="onPaste($event)"
  (input)="unsupportedBrowserPaste()">
</div>
```

If the focus is on it and I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then call the `onPaste` function with a `ClipboardEvent` and etc., the picture from the clipboard appears in the `div`.

Now I'd like to use a `<button>` to do the same process. So I thought I'd simulate the `keypress` when the button is clicked, and send the `KeyboardEvent` to the div.

I tried a lot of similar solutions but none of them worked or they are just deprecated. The last try was:

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  ctrlKey: true,
  key : "v",
  code : "86"
});
this.printedArticleImagePasteComponent.simulatePaste(event);

public simulatePaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  this.pasteDiv.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

It doesn't work of course. How is it possible to solve this?

The second idea was: get the picture from the clipboard, create a `ClipboardEvent`  manually, set the `ClipboardEvent.clipboardData.items`. But `window.clipboardData.getData` doesn't work.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, there is no way to take anything by browser (unless it's a browser plugin) from client's clipboard because it is private and it would be insecure.

Comment: However if you know what exactly is beeing copied, you can store this value, and manipulate it.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content/6413100#6413100 The solution doesn't seem to be deprecated but will cause some security prompts on some browsers according to http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboardData