# Get the contents of the Clipboard with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, clipboard

Is it possible to get the contenst of the CLipboard with JS, Jquery or PHP ?

I have seeen clipboard.js - https://clipboardjs.com/, but this only sets it not getting it back

For example, I want to open a webpage and with whatever library, access the clipboard, and then do something with it.

Maybe a workaround is to trigger the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> command and send that to a hidden textbox - not sure on how to do though.

ANy ideas ??

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current clipboard content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't believe you'll be able to achieve this, well I mean one potential way (purely theoretical & untested) capture CTRL key keydown events and set focus to a text input or text area that's hidden (if possible?) and then check if the CTRL key was used with V then you'd use what's in the text area or input.