# jQuery on Click/focus text input, set clipboard data

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

Is it possible for jQuery to autopaste clipboard data on click a text input field? 
something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="auto" id="autoset">
```

And jQuery

```
<script>
$("#autoset").on("click",function(){
    $(this).val(getClipboardData());
});
//OR
$("#autoset").on("focus",function(){
   $(this).val(getClipboardData());
});
</script>
```

I mean, how do I write the getClipboardData() function.

Comment: $("#autoset").on("click",function(){
    $(this).val(getClipboardData());
}); use this

Comment: In browsers which support it, you can use `window.clipboardData.getData('Text')`, however it will ask the user to confirm they allow the browser to access the clipboard. In browsers which do not support this, there is no way to access the clipboard in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass it as an argument in order to set value using [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method and you can combine multiple events by separating them using space.

```
$("#autoset").on("click focus",function(){
    $(this).val(getClipboardData());
    // or
    // this.value = getClipboardData();
});
```

---

Refer following question for getting clipboard data : [Get current clipboard content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content)

Comment: I think the question is more 'How do I write the `getClipboardData()` function'. I could be wrong though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes that is my point, how to I write that function

Comment: In which case please see the comment I left on the question