# Check exactly the contents of a clipboard in unix

Tags: excel, unix, vim, clipboard

I am working on parsing clipboard data in a web app to paste into various formats. In order to correctly determine how to parse the data, I need to see exactly what is in the clipboard. My current best approach is pasting into vim with `set list` and various characters to look at whitespace, however this is still missing some information.

In this example I two excel tables, where one has a merged cell in the middle. [image: excel]

Both of these copy the same data into the clipboard (according to pasting into (vim symbols represent whitespace))

[image]

Yet when pasting into google sheets it knows to preserve the merged cell (similar to my use case). What is this magic?

Comment: The answer is that the clipboard holds more than one kind of data at a time, and what comes out depends on where you paste it. The exact mechanism (and how to view that data directly) will depend a lot on what flavor of unix and window manager you're using.

Comment: Presumably this needs to work on all OSes (mainly windows) if this is a web app?

Comment: For example using Javascript on a Windows machine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content/6413100#6413100 - so you can check exactly what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answer is that the clipboard holds more than one kind of data at a time

Jordan Running was absolutely correct here, I was only seeing one data type of the clipboard, and different types were being requesting in different places. Per https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#reading-from-clipboard
there are many different types.

> - text/plain
> - text/uri-list
> - text/csv
> - text/css
> - text/html
> - application/xhtml+xml
> - image/png
> - image/jpg, image/jpeg
> - image/gif
> - image/svg+xml
> - application/xml, text/xml
> - application/javascript
> - application/json
> - application/octet-stream

In my case when pasting into Vim I was only seeing `text/plain`. While the plain text strings were exactly the same TSV data from excel, The data contained in `text/html` is how google sheets knows about the merged cell.