# Is the clipboard secure?

Tags: javascript, security, web-applications, clipboard

If I watch a web page using a web browser, can the web server read what is written in my clipboard?Is it dangerous to copy important information to the clipboard?

Comment: It looks like in older browsers it *may* be possible to get the clipboard contents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content  Users shouldn't run insecure browsers though, and doing so is at their own risk.  Any browser *should* prompt the user to ask permission for such system access.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what is your definition of `secure`. Clipboards used to be a very vulnerable back in the day but since then browsers are much better handling the request for access. Any page requesting access to your clipboard without you actually doing the `paste` should prompt the browser to notify you and request for your permission. [Here are many examples on the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=web%20page%20access%20to%20clipboard&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS738US738&oq=page%20access%20to%20clip&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.3643j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Now some users disable those warnings from the browsers and that could lead to some potential issues.