# how to paste text in TextBox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am copying text in Windows. And I need to paste my copy by clicking on a button with JQuery or Javascript.

I Search but only find a copy with jquery.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with jQuery, but you can use javascript with the `navigator.clipboard` API:

```
navigator.clipboard.readText()
  .then(text => {
     $('#myTextBox').val(text);
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current clipboard content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content)

Answer (score 0):

try this one, but its only working in IE.

```js
function Copy() {
     if(window.clipboardData) {
       window.clipboardData.clearData();
       window.clipboardData.setData("Text", document.getElementById('txtacpy').value);
     } 
    }
    function paste() {
     if(window.clipboardData) {   
       document.getElementById('txtapaste').value = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
     } 
}
```

```html
 <a href="javascript:Copy();">Copy</a>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="txtacpy" id ="txtacpy"/>
    <br />
    <a href="javascript:paste();">Paste</a>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="txtapaste"  id="txtapaste"/>
```