# How to implement paste using a button in javascript/Jquery or any front end library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, copy-paste, execcommand

Consider an editable Textarea. I have selected only 2 lines out of 5 lines & copied the some text using my button and I want to paste the text when paste button is clicked.

I tried using document.execCommand('paste'). Which is not working due to security issues in browsers.

How to implement paste using a button in javascript/Jquery or any front end library. Copy is working fine but paste using a button is not at all working.

Many cameup with solutions explaining pasting of all the content in textarea
**Remember that I need the text which got copied not the entire textarea**

Comment: Why not set the `value` of textarea or input wit the copied text?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search and I stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content)
You could try using a button that runs `window.clipboardData.getData('Text')` and use the output to put in your textArea.

Comment: bro.. I need Html in the clipboard I am able to get the Text from clipboard with ur command `window.clipboardData.getData('Text')`