# Click button doing the same as the CTRL-V event

Tags: angular

I have a function that recognizes that CTRL-V was pressed and performs the onPaste () function. I intend to do the same, but without using ctrl-v, in this case using a click on the button.

My problem is that if you do ctrl-v everything works, but if you click the button and execute the function, it doesn't work, I get the following error: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tytd2w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**code**

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
    let clipboardData = e.clipboardData || (window as any).clipboardData;
    let pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text');
    alert(pastedData)
}

<button (click)="onPaste($event)">Do the Same as PASTE (ctrl-v)</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current clipboard content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content)

Comment: @WorksLikeACharm 
Thanks for the reply. I can get this, I just can't use this function when I click the button. If you do ctrl v it works perfectly

Comment: You are sending a `ClickEvent` inside `(click)="onPaste($event)"`. Not the expected `ClipboardEvent`. So this obviously won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not the same events: When you click a `MouseEvent` is emitted, when you use ctrl+v a `ClipboardEvent` event is emitted. MouseEvent does not have `clipbordData` param, thus your error.

[image]

To get access to the clipboard on click you'll need to use the Clipboard API that will ask for access permissions.

```
  onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
    console.log(e);
    let clipboardData = e.clipboardData || (window as any).clipboardData;
    let pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text');
    alert(pastedData)
  }

  clickPaste() {
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(clipboard => alert(clipboard));
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbchgc)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! I think you put the wrong link, this is the same as the post

Comment: That way it works and I get the "image text" is there any way to get the blob, if you try to copy an image and not its address and paste it?

Answer (score 0):

On CTRL-V you get event of type ClipboardEvent which has clipboardData on it. While your click event is of type MouseEvent which has no clipboardData on it.

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrvqzq) demo to reproduce it , you can try for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in your example it continues to give the same problem :(

Comment: Example was just to give you a clearer picture of your problem. Thanks!