# Javascript - How to display a pasted clipboard image

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have a `<div>` and an `<img>` tag.

```
<div id='input' style="width: 500px; min-height: 40px; border: solid black;"></div><br>

<img id="img" style="width: 100px; min-height: 100px; border: gray;"></img>
```

Let's say I copied an image to my clipboard from my browser, and if I paste (`ctrl`+`v`) the image onto the `<div>`, the image appears at the `<img>` tag. What script is needed to achieve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503912/get-image-using-paste-from-the-browser

Comment: In case you face some trouble moving this FIle to the `<img>`, you can simply set `img.src = URL.createObjectURL( file )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use this `onPaste` event, extracting the first file in clipboard:

```
    document.getElementById('input').onpaste = (e) => {
      const eventData = window.clipboardData || e.clipboardData ;
      const theFile = eventData.files[ 0 ];
    };
```

```
    <div id='input' style="max-height: 500px; max-height: 40px; border: solid black;" contenteditable></div><br>

    <img id="img" style="width: 100px; min-height: 100px; border: gray;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/1004px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png">
```

In the example you can copy the logo and paste it in the `div`

Comment: Your js doesn't do anything useful here...

Comment: Yes, with that js you have direct access to the clipboard file and you can use it however you want.

Comment: I know that (I answered the question this one is a dupe of), but here in this live snippet it's not doing anything, the live snippet is useless.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove it