# how to paste text document.execCommand("Paste") doesn't work

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

iam traing to make a tampermonkey script auto paste some text in text box but iam confusied after many ways iam still not able to make it, i already try document.execCommand("Paste")  but nothing
document.execCommand("Paste") doesn't work! "Copy" and "cut" works fine.

```js
document.getElementById("email").execCommand('Paste');
```

Comment: This is not how execCommand is used. First you need to focus the element e.g. `document.getElementById("email").focus()` then call `document.execCommand()`.

However, the `paste` command won't work at all because it requires a special security permission which Tampermonkey doesn't provide: `clipboardRead`. No userscript extension provides that AFAIK.

You can use the new asynchronous Clipboard API instead, look for examples.

Comment: You could instead insert the text by setting the innerText/innerHTML.

Comment: [`Clipboard`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) on MDN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current clipboard content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content)