# JavaScript paste: get data

Tags: javascript, clipboard

How do you get the data from the clipboard in JavaScript? I'm calling things like:

`event.clipboardData.items[2].getAsString(x => console.log(x))`

But the inner function is never called.

You can reproduce this by running the following in Google Sheets:

```js
const input = document.createElement('input')
document.body.prepend(input)
input.onpaste = (event) => {
    event.clipboardData.items[2].getAsString(x => console.log(x))
}
```

Then copy anything from google sheets and see if the data appears in the clipboard.

You can set `onpaste` to whatever you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6413036/6355004

Comment: this works in a jsfiddle when changing it to event.clipboardData.items[0], items[2] is undefined.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be 3 items in the clipboard data?

Comment: There happen to be in this case, if you copy from sheets