# Create paste button with php

Tags: javascript, php

I want paste clipboard in many text fields so I want to create a paste button to paste anything in clipboard to a text field.

How can I create that??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. As it is now this question is off topic and will be voted down and closed

Comment: PS: Start with one of the many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623797/paste-function-in-jquery-java-script-on-button-click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste function in jquery/java script on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623797/paste-function-in-jquery-java-script-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a "paste" button PHP.  When you say paste, I am assuming you are referring to pasting what is in the clipboard.  However, this can be accomplished through JavaScript.

Here's a super nice resource on how to copy and paste in JavaScript:

https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/

Comment: I want paste text

Comment: Okay, you simply can't dot hat in PHP.  PHP is a server-side language and doesn't have much direct interaction with the client.  A client-side language, like JavaScript, would be the only way to accomplish this.

Comment: thank you for your resource