# Javascript clipboard access

Tags: javascript, browser, clipboard

Is it possible for the browser to access clipboard when user presss CTRL + C? Using pure Javascript approach.

The idea being, I have a web application that needs to be able to access the clipboard when user press the key combination.

Comment: as far as I'm aware you need to use flash for clipboard access

Comment: @DimitriAdamou and what about do this without flash?

Comment: See [`ClipboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) at MDN.

Comment: Although re-reading your question, you can just do an event that raises on ctrl + c and do your stuff (without accessing the clipoard) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604057/jquery-keypress-ctrlc-or-some-combo-like-that

Comment: @DimitriAdamou i need a data(link) that locate in clipboard

Comment: There are apparently events such as oncopy, onpaste eg `<body onpaste="callfunction();">`. Try look at this https://gist.github.com/umidjons/8612712
While not direct access to clipboard, you can at least modify what goes there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to read the clipboard in Firefox, Safari and Chrome using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233719/is-it-possible-to-read-the-clipboard-in-firefox-safari-and-chrome-using-javascr)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `navigator` clipboard.

> **Note:**
> You must preview it directly to browser when you are using Phone.

**Look!** this is all `navigator.clipboard` functions:

```
navigator.clipboard >
|—— read
|—— readText
|—— write
|—— writeText
```

to write a text to the clipboard. to this!

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText("Hello World!");
```

> **Note:**
> the object clipboard is a **Promise {}**