# Paste clipboard content to input box on button click JS

Tags: javascript, text, clipboard, paste

Could someone please give the final answer! If it possible to paste the clipboard content (text) to input box on button click?

Click the button--content in the input box, - is it possible?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard

Comment: Thank you! But this is not what I want... No tricks-- can I make it clearly in JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to read the clipboard in Firefox, Safari and Chrome using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233719/is-it-possible-to-read-the-clipboard-in-firefox-safari-and-chrome-using-javascr)

Comment: Think about it. If this would be possible, every website you visit where you click anywhere could read your clipboard. Do you *really* want this?

Comment: I knew it... :((( Thank you for making it clear!