# Is it possible in Javascript, upon button click, to paste whatever I have in my clipboard to some area/field/etc?

Tags: javascript, events, button, ecmascript-6, listener

I'm looking for a way to programmatically paste using a button click. I've tried various things from adding an event listener, or execCommand('paste').

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is a duplicate of: [Paste clipboard content to input box on button click JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023872/paste-clipboard-content-to-input-box-on-button-click-js).

I do not believe there is cross-browser support for *pasting the content's of a clipboard* on a button click. Check out [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard) for the Clipboard API. For Chrome 67, it says that, "Supports cut & copy events without a focused editable field, but does not fire paste with document.execCommand('paste')." For Firefox 61, it says, "Supports cut & copy events without a focused editable field, but not paste (presumably for security reasons)."

You can intercept paste events with something like:

```
document.addEventListener('paste', ev => {
  console.log(ev.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
});
```

But you can't get the contents of the user's clipboard without the user choosing to paste.