# Is it possible via JavaScript to access computer-copied text from another program like MS Word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, copy-paste

I have input where I want to put **copied text** of user from another program  like **MS Word** or from **browser**   into suggestion box underneath it.

Is there any  solution to do it at least in Chrome? These answers: 
 [Is it possible to read the clipboard in Firefox, Safari and Chrome using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233719/is-it-possible-to-read-the-clipboard-in-firefox-safari-and-chrome-using-javascr) and 
 [Get current clipboard content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content/6413100#6413100) and `window.clipboardData.getData('Text')` don't work properly  for me. Could someone give good solution?

Here my code ......

```js
jQuery("#video-link").focus(function() {
  var copied_obj = new ClipboardEvent('copy')
  jQuery('.suggestion').html('').html('Copied text goes here')
})

jQuery('.suggestion').click(function() {
  jQuery("#video-link").val(jQuery(this).text())
  jQuery(this).fadeOut(1000)

})
```

```css
.wrap {
  padding: 0 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 1024px;
  ma
}

#video-link {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 2%;
  width: 96%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.suggestion {
  color: #606775;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <input id="video-link" type="text" placeholder="Paste link here.." />
  <div class="suggestion"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _only_ in older IE: `clipboard.getText()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current clipboard content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content)

Comment: This would be a security issue I guess. Imagine you go to google.com and the website reads what you have in clipboard?

Comment: @ skobaljic It's possible in some browsers.

Comment: @dandavis  @ skobaljic @ Ante Jablan Adamović   so I guess in Chrome it's not possible ?

Comment: @ArtsrunHakobyan: no, it's not possible afaik, w/o extensions.

Comment: @dandavis: so only via chrome extension ?