# How to paste text from clipboard to textarea inVueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

With the `vue-clipboard2` plugin, I can copy text to clipboard using the `clipboard:copy="'Text to copy'"` directive. But the plugin seems to lack the option of pasting text from the clipboard. Is there any way I can achieve this in VueJS using pure javascript or any other plugin?

Comment: It looks that it is not possible.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content

Comment: And [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#search=clipboardData) is not that good.

Comment: Other older question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/233719/1218980

Comment: thanks guys. I guess I'll have come up with something else.