# How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

How do I copy text to the clipboard (multi-browser)?

Related: *[How does Trello access the user's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527870/how-does-trello-access-the-users-clipboard)*

Comment: This still isn't perfectly supported. You can see support on [Can I use Clipboard API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard)? which details support for the [W3C Clipboard APIs document](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/).

Answer (score 3511, accepted):

## Overview

There are three primary browser APIs for copying to the clipboard:

1. [Async Clipboard API](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#async-clipboard-api) `[navigator.clipboard.writeText]`

   - Text-focused portion available in [Chrome 66 (March 2018)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi)
   - Access is asynchronous and uses [JavaScript Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises), can be written so security user prompts (if displayed) don't interrupt the JavaScript in the page.
   - Text can be copied to the clipboard directly from a variable.
   - Only supported on pages served over HTTPS.
   - In Chrome 66 pages inactive tabs can write to the clipboard without a permissions prompt.
2. `document.execCommand('copy')` (***[deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#browser_compatibility)***)

   - Most browsers support this as of ~April 2015 (see Browser Support below).
   - Access is synchronous, i.e. stops JavaScript in the page until complete including displaying and user interacting with any security prompts.
   - Text is read from the DOM and placed on the clipboard.
   - During testing ~April 2015 only Internet Explorer was noted as displaying permissions prompts whilst writing to the clipboard.
3. Overriding the copy event

   - See Clipboard API documentation on [Overriding the copy event](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#override-copy).
   - Allows you to modify what appears on the clipboard from any copy event, can include other formats of data other than plain text.
   - Not covered here as it doesn't directly answer the question.

## General development notes

Don't expect clipboard related commands to work whilst you are testing code in the console. Generally, the page is required to be active (Async Clipboard API) or requires user interaction (e.g. a user click) to allow (`document.execCommand('copy')`) to access the clipboard see below for more detail.

### **IMPORTANT** (noted here 2020/02/20)

Note that since this post was originally written [deprecation of permissions in cross-origin IFRAMEs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes) and other [IFRAME "sandboxing"](https://blog.chromium.org/2010/05/security-in-depth-html5s-sandbox.html) prevents the embedded demos "Run code snippet" buttons and "codepen.io example" from working in some browsers (including Chrome and Microsoft Edge).

To develop create your own web page, serve that page over an HTTPS connection to test and develop against.

Here is a test/demo page which demonstrates the code working:
https://deanmarktaylor.github.io/clipboard-test/

## Async + Fallback

Due to the level of browser support for the new Async Clipboard API, you will likely want to fall back to the `document.execCommand('copy')` method to get good browser coverage.

Here is a simple example (may not work embedded in this site, read "important" note above):

```js
function fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.value = text;
  
  // Avoid scrolling to bottom
  textArea.style.top = "0";
  textArea.style.left = "0";
  textArea.style.position = "fixed";

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Fallback: Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Fallback: Oops, unable to copy', err);
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  if (!navigator.clipboard) {
    fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text);
    return;
  }
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function() {
    console.log('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
  });
}

var copyBobBtn = document.querySelector('.js-copy-bob-btn'),
  copyJaneBtn = document.querySelector('.js-copy-jane-btn');

copyBobBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  copyTextToClipboard('Bob');
});


copyJaneBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  copyTextToClipboard('Jane');
});
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
  <button class="js-copy-bob-btn">Set clipboard to BOB</button><br /><br />
  <button class="js-copy-jane-btn">Set clipboard to JANE</button>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <textarea class="js-test-textarea" cols="35" rows="4">Try pasting into here to see what you have on your clipboard:

  </textarea>
</div>
```

(codepen.io example may not work, read "important" note above)
Note that this snippet is not working well in Stack Overflow's embedded preview you can try it here: https://codepen.io/DeanMarkTaylor/pen/RMRaJX?editors=1011

## Async Clipboard API

- [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)
- [Chrome 66 announcement post (March 2018)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi)
- Reference [Async Clipboard API](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#async-clipboard-api) draft documentation

Note that there is an ability to "request permission" and test for access to the clipboard via the permissions API in Chrome 66.

```
var text = "Example text to appear on clipboard";
navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function() {
  console.log('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
}, function(err) {
  console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
});
```

## document.execCommand('copy')

The rest of this post goes into the nuances and detail of the `document.execCommand('copy')` API.

### Browser Support

<del>The JavaScript [`document.execCommand('copy')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) support has grown, see the links below for browser updates:</del>  (***[deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#browser_compatibility)***)

- Internet Explorer 10+ (although [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537834(v=vs.85).aspx) indicates some support was there from Internet Explorer 5.5+).
- [Google Chrome 43+ (~April 2015)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en)
- [Mozilla Firefox 41+ (shipping ~September 2015)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/41#Interfaces.2FAPIs.2FDOM)
- [Opera 29+ (based on Chromium 42, ~April 2015)](https://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-29/#cut-and-copy-commands)

### Simple Example

(may not work embedded in this site, read "important" note above)

```js
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.focus();
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn" style="vertical-align:top;">Copy Textarea</button>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea">Hello I'm some text</textarea>
</p>
```

### Complex Example: Copy to clipboard without displaying input

The above simple example works great if there is a `textarea` or `input` element visible on the screen.

In some cases, you might wish to copy text to the clipboard without displaying an `input` / `textarea` element. This is one example of a way to work around this (basically insert an element, copy to clipboard, remove element):

Tested with Google Chrome 44, Firefox 42.0a1, and Internet Explorer 11.0.8600.17814.

(may not work embedded in this site, read "important" note above)

```js
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");

  //
  // *** This styling is an extra step which is likely not required. ***
  //
  // Why is it here? To ensure:
  // 1. the element is able to have focus and selection.
  // 2. if the element was to flash render it has minimal visual impact.
  // 3. less flakyness with selection and copying which **might** occur if
  //    the textarea element is not visible.
  //
  // The likelihood is the element won't even render, not even a
  // flash, so some of these are just precautions. However in
  // Internet Explorer the element is visible whilst the popup
  // box asking the user for permission for the web page to
  // copy to the clipboard.
  //

  // Place in the top-left corner of screen regardless of scroll position.
  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textArea.style.top = 0;
  textArea.style.left = 0;

  // Ensure it has a small width and height. Setting to 1px / 1em
  // doesn't work as this gives a negative w/h on some browsers.
  textArea.style.width = '2em';
  textArea.style.height = '2em';

  // We don't need padding, reducing the size if it does flash render.
  textArea.style.padding = 0;

  // Clean up any borders.
  textArea.style.border = 'none';
  textArea.style.outline = 'none';
  textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';

  // Avoid flash of the white box if rendered for any reason.
  textArea.style.background = 'transparent';


  textArea.value = text;

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}


var copyBobBtn = document.querySelector('.js-copy-bob-btn'),
  copyJaneBtn = document.querySelector('.js-copy-jane-btn');

copyBobBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  copyTextToClipboard('Bob');
});


copyJaneBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  copyTextToClipboard('Jane');
});
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
  <button class="js-copy-bob-btn">Set clipboard to BOB</button><br /><br />
  <button class="js-copy-jane-btn">Set clipboard to JANE</button>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <textarea class="js-test-textarea" cols="35" rows="4">Try pasting into here to see what you have on your clipboard:

  </textarea>
</div>
```

### Additional notes

#### Only works if the user takes an action

All `document.execCommand('copy')` calls must take place as a direct result of a user action, e.g. click event handler. This is a measure to prevent messing with the user's clipboard when they don't expect it.

See the [Google Developers post here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en) for more info.

#### Clipboard API

Note the full Clipboard API draft specification can be found here:
https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/

#### Is it supported?

- `document.queryCommandSupported('copy')` should return `true` if the command "is supported by the browser".
- and `document.queryCommandEnabled('copy')` return `true` if the `document.execCommand('copy')` will succeed if called now. Checking to ensure the command was called from a user-initiated thread and other requirements are met.

However, as an example of browser compatibility issues, Google Chrome from ~April to ~October 2015 only returned `true` from `document.queryCommandSupported('copy')` if the command was called from a user-initiated thread.

Note compatibility detail below.

#### Browser Compatibility Detail

Whilst a simple call to `document.execCommand('copy')` wrapped in a `try`/`catch` block called as a result of a user click will get you the most compatibility use the following has some provisos:

Any call to `document.execCommand`, `document.queryCommandSupported` or `document.queryCommandEnabled` should be wrapped in a `try`/`catch` block.

Different browser implementations and browser versions throw differing types of exceptions when called instead of returning `false`.

Different browser implementations are still in flux and the [Clipboard API](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/) is still in draft, so remember to do your testing.

Comment: Clipboard API support is currently at 91% of global users: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_clipboard_writetext

Comment: Note on styles: I use just `opacity: 0` to conceal the `<textarea>`. Also `z-index:-1`, if you want to feel completely safe. So we actually need only three style properties to be defined: `position: fixed` and the two mentioned before.

Comment: I just added the reset of the focus after the fallback:
`var previousFocusElement = document.activeElement (....all the fallback code...) previousFocusElement.focus();`

Comment: I tried to cut this down, but really if you need the old execCommand, you need to make the textarea at least a bit visible (even `visibility: none;` doesn't work...)

Comment: As usual, the easiest and most effective method has been **deprecated and dropped**.

Comment: This is a great, thorough answer - in short, use the method described in this answer under the heading **Async + Fallback** - this is actually what Stackoverflow itself uses! [See this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70788907/422845).

Comment: I got better results w/ `window.clipboardData.setData("Text", text);` then `document.execCommand`

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers `window.clipboardData` doesn't exist, within the clipboard API `clipboardData` only exists as a property of a clipboard event, mentioned as point 3 of this answer - see https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#override-copy

Comment: Pretty sure people coming here are looking for a short snippet, with 1 or 2 qualifiers, not War and Peace.

Comment: Although this answer is really nice and seems relatively complete, it made me wonder if this isn't better handled by some package. In my case I chose: https://github.com/nkbt/react-copy-to-clipboard

Comment: The Async Clipboard API is well supported these days (https://caniuse.com/async-clipboard) so you only need those few lines under that heading. Btw: the MDN Reference for writeText has a cleaner example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText

Answer (score 1395):

Automatic copying to the clipboard may be dangerous, and therefore most browsers (except Internet Explorer) make it very difficult. Personally, I use the following simple trick:

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

The user is presented with the prompt box, where the text to be copied is already selected. Now it's enough to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (to close the box) -- and voila!

Now the clipboard copy operation is *safe*, because the user does it manually (but in a pretty straightforward way). Of course, it works in all browsers.

```html
<button id="demo" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML)">This is what I want to copy</button>

<script>
  function copyToClipboard(text) {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: But there is a limit on the amount of characters displayed in that dialog, and thus there is a limit on the amount of data to be copied.

Comment: Clever, but this only supports single line.

Comment: It's trivial to change the "prompt" function to a custom modal, the meat of the trick is to use an editable content field and pre-select the text, and that it doesn't break the browser UI by enforcing that the user take the action themselves.  A++

Comment: *"... prompt box, where the text to be copied is already selected"* - but how do you assure that the text in the prompt box is already selected?

Comment: First of all, slick solution =] But couldn't this functionality be replicated without js? (Not as simply of course.)

Comment: If your text is over 2000 characters it will be truncated, but for smaller text samples it works great

Comment: @RasTheDestroyer - Truncation at 2k chars seems to be a Chrome issue, but it's good to know regardless

Comment: @AramKocharyan I tried newlines in chrome and IE and both worked for me, it presents it without newlines but when you paste the info into an editor the newlines are preserved - IE10 & Chrome29 anyway

Comment: Its so simple way to do it..Thanks..But the text is not pr selected..is there any way to preselect the text?

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox 25.0 on OS X. I get the prompt, but the text field is empty. In Chrome it works.

Comment: @Qix It has 579 votes because there is no way to do it with pure JavaScript, as far as I know (unless your only target is IE). Sites do it "all the time" using Flash.

Comment: For mobile, in Chrome, when I select the text in the prompt it apparently doesn't allow me to copy, just cut.

Comment: Why not just using <button onclick="selectText()">Select text (press Ctrl+C to copy)</button>  and function selectText() {
  const input = document.getElementById('text-box');
  input.focus();
  input.select();
} I think it quicker.

Comment: I used it on onload body tag and also onClick, and works great on android chrome and web.

Answer (score 527):

The following approach works in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Edge, and in recent versions of Safari (copy support was added in version 10 which was released Oct 2016).

- Create a textarea and set its contents to the text you want copied to the clipboard.
- Append the textarea to the DOM.
- Select the text in the textarea.
- Call document.execCommand("copy")
- Remove the textarea from the dom.

Note: you will not see the textarea, as it is added and removed within the same synchronous invocation of Javascript code.

Some things to watch out for if you are implementing this yourself:

- For security reasons, this can only called from an event handler such as click (Just as with opening windows).
- Internet Explorer will show a permission dialog the first time the clipboard is updated.
- Internet Explorer, and Edge will scroll when the textarea is focused.
- execCommand() may throw in some cases.
- Newlines and tabs can get swallowed unless you use a textarea. (Most articles seem to recommend using a div)
- The textarea will be visible while the Internet Explorer dialog is shown, you either need to hide it, or use the Internet Explorer specific clipboardData API.
- In Internet Explorer system administrators can disable the clipboard API.

The function below should handle all of the following issues as cleanly as possible. Please leave a comment if you find any problems or have any suggestions for improving it.

```js
// Copies a string to the clipboard. Must be called from within an
// event handler such as click. May return false if it failed, but
// this is not always possible. Browser support for Chrome 43+,
// Firefox 42+, Safari 10+, Edge and Internet Explorer 10+.
// Internet Explorer: The clipboard feature may be disabled by
// an administrator. By default a prompt is shown the first
// time the clipboard is used (per session).
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
        // Internet Explorer-specific code path to prevent textarea being shown while dialog is visible.
        return window.clipboardData.setData("Text", text);

    }
    else if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.textContent = text;
        textarea.style.position = "fixed";  // Prevent scrolling to bottom of page in Microsoft Edge.
        document.body.appendChild(textarea);
        textarea.select();
        try {
            return document.execCommand("copy");  // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
            return prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
        }
        finally {
            document.body.removeChild(textarea);
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fx6a6n6x/

Comment: Nice answer : cross browser support, error handling + clean up. As of today's new support for queryCommandSupported, copying to clipboard is now feasible in Javascript and this should be the accepted answer, instead of awkward 'window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text)' workaround. window.clipboardData is supported in IE9, so you should add IE9 in the browser support list and I think maybe IE8 and previous also, but need to verify.

Comment: Yeah. IE 8/9 Should be ok. Our app doesn't support them. So I haven't tested. IE stops support in Jan, so I'm not too fussed. Hopefully Safari support will land soon. I'm sure it's on their radar.

Comment: @SantiagoCorredoira: In 2016, this deserves to be the accepted answer. Please consider reassigning the BGT (big green tick).

Comment: @drooh It is supported in Safari 10+. Safari 10 is still in beta. It will be released with the MacOS 10.12 (probably in October).

Comment: textarea.select() does not work for me on Chrome. The function exists but the contents of the text area do not actually get into the clipboard

Comment: Did you try the code in JS Fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/fx6a6n6x/  This works for me in chrome and canary on MacOS.

Comment: If focus is not in the html document, like say you just clicked Windows task bar, and then you click the Copy button in your html document, the function returns `true` but it fails to copy. This was the case in Firefox 55 for me today. But thanks for sharing this, I am using it, very much appreciated.

Comment: @Noitidart I Tested and it works perfectly for firefox 54, chrome 60 and edge browser, even when focus is not in the html document, the error you're having is probably specific to version FF 55

Comment: Thanks @TosinJohn - may you please open the dev tools, then focus that, then with your first click - click the `<button>` that triggers the copy, it should return true but the copy will fail.

Comment: @Noitidart It still works perfectly here, focusing on dev tools didn't stop it. And by the way, what will a normal web app user be doing on developer tools

Comment: Thanks @TosinJohn - this is very interesting. I don't know why my first copy is failing. Thanks so much for that test. Yes true they might not be in dev tools, but they may have two windows next to each other and click from one window into my web app (first click being on the copy).

Comment: the command:clipboardData,setData ("Text",text) doesn't copy formatted text, so, for example, if you copied a text containing several lines (with new line chars as separators), the new line char won't be part of the copied string, and instead you'll get one long string

Comment: **jQuery UI users**: Note that you'll run into problems with this method if you try to use this function from within a modal dialog box. I suspect it's because the jQuery UI modal is managing/manipulating the document focus. If it fits your use case, one workaround is to close the modal dialog first and then copy the text. Or, to simply use a non-modal dialog box. I suspect you may also be able to modify this function so it adds the textarea to the modal instead of to the body.

Comment: i'm probably asking the wrong questions in the wrong place, but feel like trying it anyway... could this be made into a two liner, by using some sort of trusted always updated import from gitlab or something?

Comment: needs a fix, there's a great "if" guard to check that window.clipboardData.setData is available, but then if it passes the code bypasses window and hits "clipboardData" direct!  I added code asis to a CRA and it splatted, just needs window. prefix

Answer (score 173):

Here is my take on that one...

```
function copy(text) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', text);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    var result = document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input);
    return result;
 }
```

@korayem: Note that using html `input` field won't respect line breaks `\n` and will flatten any text into a single line.

As mentioned by @nikksan in the comments, using `textarea` will fix the problem as follows:

```
function copy(text) {
    var input = document.createElement('textarea');
    input.innerHTML = text;
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    var result = document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Not working in Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 on Win10x64

Comment: For some reason my usual "create a hidden input or textarea, then select it and execCommand" wasn't working, and this was by far the best solution listed here, even though others are comprehensive and like complete wikipedia pages, this one worked well for me, so +1

Answer (score 101):

Reading and modifying the clipboard from a webpage raises security and privacy concerns. However, in Internet Explorer, it is possible to do it. I found this [example snippet](http://www.sajithmr.com/onclick-select-all-and-copy-to-clipboard-javascript/):

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function select_all(obj) {
            var text_val=eval(obj);
            text_val.focus();
            text_val.select();
            r = text_val.createTextRange();
            if (!r.execCommand) return; // feature detection
            r.execCommand('copy');
        }
    </script>
    <input value="http://www.sajithmr.com"
     onclick="select_all(this)" name="url" type="text" />
```

Comment: Using flash for a simple copy operation seems like overkill, glad there was a clean JS way to do this.  And since we are in a corporate env. IE is just fine. Thanks Bandi!

Comment: plz explain what `execCommand(\\’copy\\’);` does, if not copy to clipboard for IE ? @mrBorna

Comment: Do not use `if(!document.all)` but `if(!r.execCommand)` lest anybody else implements it! Document.all is absolutely non-relevant to this.

Comment: How come these privacy concerns were never raised for a decade when people were using Flash to alter the clipboard? And if we only allow one way (i-e copying, and not reading its content) how does that generate a privacy concern?

Comment: @MuhammadbinYusrat: Although not a privacy concern, it _is_ a UX concern. Consider that the user has copied something and think he knows what is on the clipboard, then browsing your site, and suddenly the clipboard contains something he hasn't asked for, and he has lost what he copied in the first place.

Answer (score 93):

If you want a really simple solution (takes less than 5 minutes to integrate) and looks good right out of the box, then [Clippy](http://github.com/mojombo/clippy) is a nice alternative to some of the more complex solutions.

It was written by a cofounder of GitHub. Example Flash embed code below:

```xml
<object
    classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
    width="110"
    height="14"
    id="clippy">

    <param name="movie" value="/flash/clippy.swf"/>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
    <param name="quality" value="high"/>
    <param name="scale" value="noscale"/>
    <param NAME="FlashVars" value="text=#{text}"/>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#{bgcolor}"/>
    <embed
        src="/flash/clippy.swf"
        width="110"
        height="14"
        name="clippy"
        quality="high"
        allowScriptAccess="always"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
        FlashVars="text=#{text}"
        bgcolor="#{bgcolor}"/>
</object>
```

Remember to replace `#{text}` with the text you need copied, and `#{bgcolor}` with a color.

Comment: For anyone interested, check Clippy being used on GitHub when copying the URL for the repo.

Answer (score 83):

I have recently written a [technical blog post](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/) on this very problem (I work at Lucidchart and we recently did an overhaul on our clipboard).

Copying plain text to the clipboard is relatively simple, assuming you attempt to do it during a system copy event (user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or uses the browser's menu).

```js
var isIe = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie")    != -1 ||
            navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("trident") != -1);

document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
    var textToPutOnClipboard = "This is some text";
    if (isIe) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', textToPutOnClipboard);
    } else {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', textToPutOnClipboard);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Putting text on the clipboard not during a system copy event is much more difficult. It looks like some of these other answers reference ways to do it via Flash, which is the only cross-browser way to do it (so far as I understand).

Other than that, there are some options on a browser-by-browser basis.

This is the most simple in Internet Explorer, where you can access the clipboardData object at anytime from JavaScript via:

```js
window.clipboardData
```

(When you attempt to do this outside of a system cut, copy, or paste event, however, Internet Explorer will prompt the user to grant the web application clipboard permission.)

In Chrome, you can create a Chrome extension that will give you [clipboard permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) (this is what we do for Lucidchart). Then for users with your extension installed you'll just need to fire the system event yourself:

```js
document.execCommand('copy');
```

It looks like Firefox has [some options](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard) that allow users to grant permissions to certain sites to access the clipboard, but I haven't tried any of these personally.

Comment: Not mentioned in the blog post (I'm hoping to update it in the near future), is the ability to trigger cut and copy using execCommand. This is supported in IE10+, Chrome 43+, and Opera29+. Read about it here. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands

Comment: A problem with this is that it hijacks other normal copy events.

Answer (score 74):

I like this one:

```
<input onclick="this.select();" type='text' value='copy me' />
```

If a user doesn't know how to copy text in their OS, then it's likely they don't know how to paste either.  So just have it automatically selected, leaving the rest to the user.

Comment: I like it too, because it's short. You can also copy : `<input onclick="this.select(); document.execCommand('copy');" type='text' value='copy me' />`

Answer (score 59):

[clipboard.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-js) is a small, non-Flash, utility that allows copying of text or HTML data to the clipboard. It's very easy to use, just include the .js and use something like this:

```
<button id='markup-copy'>Copy Button</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('markup-copy').addEventListener('click', function() {
  clipboard.copy({
    'text/plain': 'Markup text. Paste me into a rich text editor.',
    'text/html': '<i>here</i> is some <b>rich text</b>'
  }).then(
    function(){console.log('success'); },
    function(err){console.log('failure', err);
  });

});
</script>
```

clipboard.js is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/lgarron/clipboard.js).

> **Note:** This has been deprecated now. Migrate to [here](https://github.com/lgarron/clipboard-polyfill).

Comment: This library is used by angular.io for its Tour of Hero and fallback in graceful mode for browser not supporting execCommand by displaying a preselected text the user has just to copy.

Comment: Looks either clipboard.js has been replaced, or forked, but it seems to live on and is actively maintained at https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard

Answer (score 47):

In 2018, here's how you can go about it:

```
async copySomething(text?) {
  try {
    const toCopy = text || location.href;
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(toCopy);
    console.log('Text or Page URL copied');
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
  }
}
```

It is used in my Angular 6+ code like so:

```
<button mat-menu-item (click)="copySomething()">
    <span>Copy link</span>
</button>
```

If I pass in a string, it copies it. If nothing, it copies the page's URL.

More gymnastics to the clipboard stuff can be done too. See more information here:

*[Unblocking Clipboard Access](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi)*

Comment: you've linked to localhost

Comment: Please be aware that this does not work in Safari (version 11.1.2)

Comment: @arjun27 Well hopefully someday Apple will catch up. Although this https://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard shows the above version you mentioned to be partially supported.

Comment: According to the link provided, "navigator.clipboard is only supported for pages served over HTTPS"

Answer (score 46):

I use this very successfully (**without** jQuery or any other framework).

```
function copyToClp(txt){
    var m = document;
    txt = m.createTextNode(txt);
    var w = window;
    var b = m.body;
    b.appendChild(txt);
    if (b.createTextRange) {
        var d = b.createTextRange();
        d.moveToElementText(txt);
        d.select();
        m.execCommand('copy');
    } 
    else {
        var d = m.createRange();
        var g = w.getSelection;
        d.selectNodeContents(txt);
        g().removeAllRanges();
        g().addRange(d);
        m.execCommand('copy');
        g().removeAllRanges();
    }
    txt.remove();
}
```

*Warning*

Tabs are converted to spaces (at least in Chrome).

Comment: Doesnt work on firefox, i got an error saying that there was a lack of user activation

Comment: @Luke_ Is firefox right? Did you call it without a direct user's click?

Comment: Without problems in FF 111.0.1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 40):

Best and Easy way in JavaScript/TypeScript use this command

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(textExample);
```

just pass your value what you want to copy to clipboard in **textExample**

Comment: navigator.clipboard can be udenfined. You should catch this exception...

Comment: Doesn't work with IOS

Comment: According to MDN Clipboard docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard), this feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

Comment: It's always nice to see a one line solution that works. The selected answer is okay, but sometimes long answers can be too much when trying to make something work.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me

Answer (score 37):

ZeroClipboard is the best cross-browser solution I've found:

```
<div id="copy" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!">Click to copy</div>
<script src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script>
  var clip = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('copy') );
</script>
```

If you need non-Flash support for iOS you just add a fall-back:

```
clip.on( 'noflash', function ( client, args ) {
    $("#copy").click(function(){
        var txt = $(this).attr('data-clipboard-text');
        prompt ("Copy link, then click OK.", txt);
    });
});
```

http://zeroclipboard.org/

https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard

Comment: cross-browser with Flash ? not working in iOS and Android 4.4

Comment: See updated answer. This allows less steps for flash-users and a fall-back for everyone else.

Comment: it has a billion lines of code. it's absolutely ridicules. better not to do it at all than including such a monster in a project

Comment: There is a simple version https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/8698897 that is 20K that doesn't have all the bells and whistles in the 74k version. Neither is very large. My guess is most users are okay with the extra milliseconds that a 74k or a 20k file being downloaded will take so copy/paste is one click instead of two.

Comment: @Justin I just can't make it work locally, even if I copy&paste the examples (I make minimum changes, e.g. the value of `src` in script tags). I feel that their documentation is pretty but inefficient.

Answer (score 31):

Since Chrome 42+ and Firefox 41+ now support the **document.execCommand('copy')** command, I created a couple of functions for a cross-browser copy-to-clipboard ability using a combination of [Tim Down's old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024509/4307527) and [Google Developer's answer](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en):

```js
function selectElementContents(el) {
    // Copy textarea, pre, div, etc.
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        // Internet Explorer
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.select();
        textRange.execCommand("Copy");
    }
    else if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        // Non-Internet Explorer
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
        }
    }
} // end function selectElementContents(el)

function make_copy_button(el) {
    var copy_btn = document.createElement('input');
    copy_btn.type = "button";
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(copy_btn, el.nextSibling);
    copy_btn.onclick = function() {
        selectElementContents(el);
    };

    if (document.queryCommandSupported("copy") || parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./)[2]) >= 42) {
        // Copy works with Internet Explorer 4+, Chrome 42+, Firefox 41+, Opera 29+
        copy_btn.value = "Copy to Clipboard";
    }
    else {
        // Select only for Safari and older Chrome, Firefox and Opera
        copy_btn.value = "Select All (then press Ctrl + C to Copy)";
    }
}
/* Note: document.queryCommandSupported("copy") should return "true" on browsers that support copy,
    but there was a bug in Chrome versions 42 to 47 that makes it return "false".  So in those
    versions of Chrome feature detection does not work!
    See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476508
*/

make_copy_button(document.getElementById("markup"));
```

```html
<pre id="markup">
  Text that can be copied or selected with cross browser support.
</pre>
```

Answer (score 27):

I am loath to add another answer on this, but to help rookies like me, and because this is the top Google result I will.

In 2022 to copy text to the clipboard you use **one line**.

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy);
```

This returns a Promise that is resolved if it copies, or rejects if it fails.

A full working function is this:

```
async function copyTextToClipboard(textToCopy) {
    try {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy);
        console.log('copied to clipboard')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('failed to copy to clipboard. error=' + error);
    }
}
```

WARNING! *If you have Chrome Dev Tools open while testing this it will fail* because for the browser to enable the clipboard, it requires you to have the window in focus. This is to prevent random websites changing your clipboard if you don't want it. Dev Tools steals this focus so close Dev Tools and your test will work.

If you want to copy other things (images, etc) to the clipboard, look at these docs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

This is well supported enough in browsers you can use it. If you are worried about Firefox, use a Permissions Query to show or hide the button if the browser supports it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query

Comment: async copyToClipboard(){
let text = "text on clipboard";
await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);

}


After calling this function you will get to know that the desired value of variable text you can able to paste anywhere from clipboard .

Answer (score 26):

The other methods will copy plain text to the clipboard. To copy HTML (i.e., you can paste results into a WYSIWYG editor), you can do the following in Internet Explorer *only*. This is is fundamentally different from the other methods, as the browser actually visibly selects the content.

```
// Create an editable DIV and append the HTML content you want copied
var editableDiv = document.createElement("div");
with (editableDiv) {
    contentEditable = true;
}
editableDiv.appendChild(someContentElement);

// Select the editable content and copy it to the clipboard
var r = document.body.createTextRange();
r.moveToElementText(editableDiv);
r.select();
r.execCommand("Copy");

// Deselect, so the browser doesn't leave the element visibly selected
r.moveToElementText(someHiddenDiv);
r.select();
```

Comment: see more complete HTML solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191780/javascript-copy-string-to-clipboard-as-text-html

Answer (score 26):

I found the following solution:

The on-key-down handler creates a "pre" tag. We set the content to copy to this tag, and then make a selection on this tag and return true in the handler. This calls the standard handler of Chrome and copies selected text.

And if you need it, you may set the timeout for a function for restoring the previous selection. My implementation on [MooTools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools):

```
function EnybyClipboard() {
    this.saveSelection = false;
    this.callback = false;
    this.pastedText = false;

    this.restoreSelection = function() {
        if (this.saveSelection) {
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            for (var i = 0; i < this.saveSelection.length; i++) {
                window.getSelection().addRange(this.saveSelection[i]);
            }
            this.saveSelection = false;
        }
    };

    this.copyText = function(text) {
        var div = $('special_copy');
        if (!div) {
            div = new Element('pre', {
                'id': 'special_copy',
                'style': 'opacity: 0;position: absolute;top: -10000px;right: 0;'
            });
            div.injectInside(document.body);
        }
        div.set('text', text);
        if (document.createRange) {
            var rng = document.createRange();
            rng.selectNodeContents(div);
            this.saveSelection = [];
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            for (var i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; i++) {
                this.saveSelection[i] = selection.getRangeAt(i);
            }
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(rng);
            setTimeout(this.restoreSelection.bind(this), 100);
        } else return alert('Copy did not work. :(');
    };

    this.getPastedText = function() {
        if (!this.pastedText) alert('Nothing to paste. :(');
        return this.pastedText;
    };

    this.pasteText = function(callback) {
        var div = $('special_paste');
        if (!div) {
            div = new Element('textarea', {
                'id': 'special_paste',
                'style': 'opacity: 0;position: absolute;top: -10000px;right: 0;'
            });
            div.injectInside(document.body);
            div.addEvent('keyup', function() {
                if (this.callback) {
                    this.pastedText = $('special_paste').get('value');
                    this.callback.call(null, this.pastedText);
                    this.callback = false;
                    this.pastedText = false;
                    setTimeout(this.restoreSelection.bind(this), 100);
                }
            }.bind(this));
        }
        div.set('value', '');
        if (document.createRange) {
            var rng = document.createRange();
            rng.selectNodeContents(div);
            this.saveSelection = [];
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            for (var i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; i++) {
                this.saveSelection[i] = selection.getRangeAt(i);
            }
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(rng);
            div.focus();
            this.callback = callback;
        } else return alert('Failed to paste. :(');
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
enyby_clip = new EnybyClipboard(); // Init

enyby_clip.copyText('some_text'); // Place this in the Ctrl+C handler and return true;

enyby_clip.pasteText(function callback(pasted_text) {
    alert(pasted_text);
}); // Place this in Ctrl+V handler and return true;
```

On paste, it creates a textarea and works the same way.

PS: Maybe this solution can be used for creating a full cross-browser solution without Flash. It works in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Has anyone tried that out? Sounds like a nifty thingy, in case it really works on a range of browsers!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H2FHC/ Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/H2FHC/show/ Please open it and press Ctrl+V or Ctrl+C. In FF 19.0 forks perfectly. In Chrome 25.0.1364.97 m too. Opera 12.14 - OK. Safari 5.1.7 for Windows - OK. IE - FAIL.

Comment: For IE need run focus on element inside page. See http://fiddle.jshell.net/H2FHC/3/show/ and http://fiddle.jshell.net/H2FHC/3/ Worked in IE 9/10. IE 6/7 need process create selection in other way because document.createRange not supported.

Answer (score 26):

I've put together what I think is the best one.

- Uses cssText to avoid exceptions in Internet Explorer as opposed to style directly.
- Restores selection if there was one
- Sets read-only so the keyboard doesn't come up on mobile devices
- Has a workaround for iOS so that it actually works as it normally blocks execCommand.

Here it is:

```
const copyToClipboard = (function initClipboardText() {
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');

  // Move it off-screen.
  textarea.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; left: -99999em';

  // Set to readonly to prevent mobile devices opening a keyboard when
  // text is .select()'ed.
  textarea.setAttribute('readonly', true);

  document.body.appendChild(textarea);

  return function setClipboardText(text) {
    textarea.value = text;

    // Check if there is any content selected previously.
    const selected = document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0 ?
      document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) : false;

    // iOS Safari blocks programmatic execCommand copying normally, without this hack.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|ipod|iphone/i)) {
      const editable = textarea.contentEditable;
      textarea.contentEditable = true;
      const range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(textarea);
      const sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
      textarea.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
      textarea.contentEditable = editable;
    }
    else {
      textarea.select();
    }

    try {
      const result = document.execCommand('copy');

      // Restore previous selection.
      if (selected) {
        document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        document.getSelection().addRange(selected);
      }

      return result;
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    }
  };
})();
```

Usage: `copyToClipboard('some text')`

Comment: Doesn't work in Opera etc.

Answer (score 19):

This code tested @ 2021 May . Work on Chrome , IE , Edge. 'message' parameter on below is the string value you want to copy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copyToClipboard(message) {
        var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textArea.value = message;
        textArea.style.opacity = "0"; 
        document.body.appendChild(textArea);
        textArea.focus();
        textArea.select();


        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            alert('Copying text command was ' + msg);
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Unable to copy value , error : ' + err.message);
        }

        document.body.removeChild(textArea);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 18):

This works straight away, using the newest [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API), and a user interaction:

```js
copy.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => navigator.clipboard.writeText("Hello World!"))
```

```html
<button id="copy">Copy Hello World!</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: It works if you add .then() to the .writeText(), since it's a Promise.

Answer (score 13):

Copy text from HTML input to the clipboard:

```js
 function myFunction() {
   /* Get the text field */
   var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

   /* Select the text field */
   copyText.select();

   /* Copy the text inside the text field */
   document.execCommand("Copy");

   /* Alert the copied text */
   alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
 }
```

```html
 <!-- The text field -->
 <input type="text" value="Hello Friend" id="myInput">

 <!-- The button used to copy the text -->
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

**Note:** *The `document.execCommand()` method is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier.*

**Source**: [W3Schools - *Copy Text to Clipboard*](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

Answer (score 13):

Best Way to Copy the text inside the text field.
Use **navigator.clipboard.writeText**.

```
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myId">
<button onclick="myFunction()" >Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myId");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}

</script>
```

Comment: document.execCommand('Copy'); command doesn't work's always, and above approach solved it

Comment: document.execCommand('Copy'); command works but

The signature '(commandId: string, showUI?: boolean | undefined, value?: string | undefined): boolean' of 'document.execCommand' is deprecated

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem building a custom grid edit from (something like Excel) and compatibility with Excel. I had to support selecting multiple cells, copying and pasting.

Solution: create a textarea where you will be inserting data for the user to copy (for me when the user is selecting cells), set focus on it (for example, when user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) and select the whole text.

So, when the user hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> he/she gets copied cells he/she selected. After testing just resizing the textarea to one pixel (I didn't test if it will be working on display:none). It works nicely on all browsers, and it is transparent to the user.

Pasting - you could do same like this (differs on your target) - keep focus on textarea and catch paste events using onpaste (in my project I use textareas in cells to edit).

I can't paste an example (commercial project), but you get the idea.

Answer (score 9):

This is an expansion of [Chase Seibert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript/400403#400403), with the advantage that it will work for IMAGE and TABLE elements, not just DIVs on Internet Explorer 9.

```
if (document.createRange) {
    // Internet Explorer 9 and modern browsers
    var r = document.createRange();
    r.setStartBefore(to_copy);
    r.setEndAfter(to_copy);
    r.selectNode(to_copy);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.addRange(r);
    document.execCommand('Copy');  // Does nothing on Firefox
} else {
    // Internet Explorer 8 and earlier. This stuff won't work
    // on Internet Explorer 9.
    // (unless forced into a backward compatibility mode,
    // or selecting plain divs, not img or table).
    var r = document.body.createTextRange();
    r.moveToElementText(to_copy);
    r.select()
    r.execCommand('Copy');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I have used clipboard.js.

We can get it on npm:

```
npm install clipboard --save
```

And also on [Bower](https://bower.io/)

```
bower install clipboard --save
```

```js
new ClipboardJS("#btn1");

document.querySelector("#btn2").addEventListener("click", () => document.querySelector("#btn1").dataset.clipboardText = Math.random());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2.0.8/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1" data-clipboard-text="Text to copy goes here">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>
<button id="btn2">Click here to change data-clipboard-text</button>

<br /><br />

<input type="text" placeholder="Paste here to see clipboard" />
```

More usage & examples are at https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/.

Comment: I was afraid that it wasn't compatible with dynamic content, but it is ;-)
I think it's the better solution, NOW, than the old one of 2008.

Comment: They say: *"[While Bower is maintained, we recommend using Yarn and Webpack or Parcel for front-end projects](https://bower.io/)"*

Answer (score 6):

My bad. This only works in Internet Explorer.

Here's yet another way to copy text:

```
<p>
    <a onclick="window.clipboardData.setData('text', document.getElementById('Test').innerText);">Copy</a>
</p>
```

Comment: This does not work in current Chrome (V31) or FireFox (v25). Error is that  window.clipboardData is undefined. On the plus side, it works in IE9. So as long as you don't care about good browsers and want to lock your site into using bad ones, this is the way for you to do it!

Comment: i don't get why so many silly answers. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard

Answer (score 4):

Here is the **simple** Ajax/session based clipboard for the same website.

Note that the session must be enabled & valid and this solution works for the same site. I tested it on CodeIgniter, but I ran into session/Ajax problem, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980193/codeigniter-session-bugging-out-with-ajax-calls) solved that problem too. If you don't want to play with sessions, use a database table.

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#copy_btn_id").click(function(){

            $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>ajax/foo_copy/"+$(this).val(), null,
                function(data){
                    // Copied successfully
                }, "html"
            );
        });

        $("#paste_btn_id").click(function() {

           $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>ajax/foo_paste/", null,
               function(data) {
                   $('#paste_btn_id').val(data);
               }, "html"
           );
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML content**

```
<input type='text' id='copy_btn_id' onclick='this.select();'  value='myvalue' />
<input type='text' id='paste_btn_id' value='' />
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
    class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

        public function foo_copy($val){
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('clipboard_val' => $val));
        }

        public function foo_paste(){
            echo $this->session->userdata('clipboard_val');
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```