# Check if copy and paste is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, paste

On Firefox (at least) JavaScript copy and paste functions are disabled by default.
Is there anyway to check if the functionality is available so i can hide some buttons if its not?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome

Comment: Not related, that post is to do with accesses the clipboard, I just need to check if I can/cant access it.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in IE8, FF3.6.10, Chrome 3.0.195. Safari 4.0:

```
if(typeof(window.clipboardData)=="undefined") {
  alert("not working")
}
else {
  alert("working")
}
```