# copy contents of div to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Copy to Clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)

Is there a way to copy the contents of a div into a clipboard using javascript/jquery without using an external plugin?

Comment: It can't be done in Javascript in all browsers. [Take a look at this (possible duplicate) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can but only for IE, to do for all browsers you need Flash

P.S the best solution is http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/ and not the answer in the question that a couple of people have linked to already