# clipboard issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have been trying for few hours to get the data copied in the clipboard in chrome its working in IE chrome gives me an error the sample code follows

```
window.clipboardData.getData("Text")
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome

Answer (score 4):

Chrome doesn't allow access to the clipboard.

It doesn't even have a `window.clipboardData` object.

A workaround is to possibly use a hidden Flash movie.

Comment: What my requirement is "I have copied some content from a document and want to paste the content in a text area of my application so i need to check the maxlength of that textarea and paste accordingly"

Comment: @mathew Why don't you use a textbox instead? or put an on change that removes the extra text with a message that the user has exceeded the maxlength?

Comment: @James Khoury same thing happens for text box with property set as multiline

Comment: @Mathew You don't need to on a text input as it has a size attribute you can set.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve clipboardData from event in your function. 
In your "paste" event handler (pure Javascript) use `event.clipboardData` or `event.originalEvent.clipboardData` in JQuery event handler

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does give you access to the paste event and you can create a class naming structure to take advantage. Here i am updating a RadMaskedTextBox to use a css class on the parent span and then use the following code where "NumericBlur" is my input box's parent wrappercssclass.

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="SSN" runat="server" Width="100" RequireCompleteText="false" WrapperCssClass="NumericBlur rdfInput"  Mask="###-##-####"></telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>


 window.addEventListener('paste', function (event) {

    var data = event.clipboardData.getData('text');

    if (event.srcElement.parentElement.className.contains("NumericBlur")) {

        event.srcElement.value=data.replace(/\D/g, "");
    }
});
```

'

Answer (score 0):

Browsers these days don't allow that. You will have to go with a hidden flash object to be able to copy to the clipboard.

Here is a flash copy to clipboard system, [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/). You could also try [ZerioClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/).

Most websites do this if they want something to be copied to the clipboard. [Bit.ly](http://bit.ly) uses flash to copy the link. See:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this issue is still live but it is possible to read the windows clipboard using the Chrome: document.execCommand('paste') command.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still in search, this snippet could be useful:

```
window.addEventListener('paste', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = event.clipboardData.getData('text');

    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Combining both rodk_walker and tenbits answers, it works for chrome and firefox "event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text')". At least for now (march 2015).  Thank you both.