# Cross-Browser JS/jQuery Copy current URL to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, copy, clipboard

I've been exploring ways to have a button to copy the current URL to the user's clipboard that is cross-browser compatible, but doesn't require Flash. I thought there would be a jQuery or vanilla JavaScript solution, but haven't come across anything yet.

I've found solutions like Zero Clipboard (http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) but it uses  a Flash movie file.

Is there no way around utilizing Flash if it's cross-browser compatible.

Comment: For security reasons, I don't think its possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome

Comment: So with that being said, what's the best cross-browser way to grab the URL? Is it Zero Clipboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I have read its [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome).

Also according to some research ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript), [here](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/javascript-copy-to-clipboard.html)), [Zero Clipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) seems to be the way people are going about doing this.

Comment: Though that site now says "Development Has Ceased On Zero Clipboard" so use at at your own potentially lack of future-proofing risk :-)