# How to obtain data from clipboard in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, clipboard

I would like to trigger onpaste event on  element to retrieve data in clipboard (I want to check if image exists in clipboard and upload it into the server). It works perfect on Chrome:

```
$('#textarea')[0].onpaste = function(event)
{
    var items = event.clipboardData.items;

    if (items.length)
    {
        var blob = items[0].getAsFile();
        var fr = new FileReader();

        fr.onload = function(e)
        {
            alert('got it!');
        }

        fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
}
```

Does not work on Firefox: `event.clipboardData.items` does not exists. Do you have any idea how to retrive onpaste event in  element?

Comment: Firefox does not allow you to access the clipboard because of security reasons. Anyway your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome

Answer (score 2):

You need to create one contenteditable div which will hold the image on paste

```
var pasteCatcher = $('<div/>',{'id':'container'});
$('body').append(pasteCatcher);
var pasteCatcher = document.getElementById('container');
               pasteCatcher.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
```

then you need to wait for paste event and process it

```
 window.addEventListener("paste",processEvent);
function processEvent(e) {
//some functionality
}
```

Also write the code to grab the image data from contenteditable div and send it to server.

Answer (score 1):

It seems not. Sorry.

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Granting%20JavaScript%20access%20to%20the%20clipboard

[JavaScript get clipboard data on paste event (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)

Comment: At leas the first link is not really related; that's about full, unconditional access to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Sure I can. In this example I retrieve image from clipboard after using Ctrl+V:

```
 <div id="foo" style="width: 200px; height: 200px" contenteditable="true">Paste here!</div>
 $('#foo')[0].onpaste = function(e)
{                   
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        var blob = $('#foo img').attr('src');


        $.post('/upload/image', {'data': blob}, function(result)
        {


        }, 'json'); 

    }, 200);
}
```

It works with `<div>` element that has `contenteditable` attribute, but does not work with `<textarea>`

P.S. Sorry for answering my own question but this piece of code might help someone.

Comment: Hey i need your help. Your solution is correct but i have one doubt if contenteditable div is already contains 2 images and when i Crtl+V then it upload total 3 images on server ?

Comment: Well... above code uploads everything that is in `src` attribute.

Comment: i know it upload src attribute value, but i want to know if there is 3 src already available in the div then it upload total 4 src ( in which 3 is already there and 4th is newly pasted ) ??