# how to use .getelementbyID and copy inner html - VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, dom, getelementbyid

So I have set up my references to Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft Internet controls, and an example to input a value by getting an element id is below:

```
With HTMLDoc

.getElementById("USER").setAttribute "value", "myuser"
.getElementById("PASSWORD").setAttribute "value", "mypass"
.getElementById("Button").Click

End With
```

What Im curious to know, is, lets say there was an ID tag named "ReturnValue" that contained a string in the inner html that I wanted to copy to clipboard, how would I use .getElementByID and COPY in that instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the innerHTML like this:

```
TxtHtml = .getElementById("elementId").InnerHtml
```

You can then set the clipboard text from VBA: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/ManipulateClipboard.htm

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I used
    strFirst12Chars = Left$(TXTHTML, 12)

To give me the first 12 characters back, what if it is enclosed in <a> tags lets say, do we use the same concept?

Comment: VBA has `Left()` which you can use to get the first x characters of a string.  If you just want the text content (no html) then use innerText instead of innerHtml

Answer (score -1):

Use JQuery to access innerHtml or Html whatever you want.

```
var textToCopy = $(#ReturnValue).innerHtml();
```

For copying text to clipboard, you can refer [Copy / Put text on the clipboard with FireFox, Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome)

Comment: I am not using Javascript, I am using VBA, with IE, for automation (no access to other browsers).  I notice there are a lot of javascript references but not many VBA on the subject. Thanks for the reply, though.