# GXT / GWT / Javascript - Copy data to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, gxt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

I have a text and I'd like to copy the data to the computer's clipboard. 
Is there a widget to do so in GXT, if not, is there in GWT, if not, which is the low level Javascript way?

Do all browsers support it ?

Comment: I think only IE supports that, but I've seen it done with Flash..

Comment: What's wrong with users doing it themselves (right click + copy)?

Comment: Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome