# copy to clipboard - not working in FF,Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I am using below mentioned javascript to copy the text to clipboard. Its working in IE, but not working in Firefox and Chrome.

Please advice me,What is wrong?

```
   function setDataToclipboard() 
{

var str=document.getElementById("populatedString").value; 

if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData) {
    clipboardData.setData("Text", str);
    alert("Copied!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

w3c clipboard api is been implemented by all the browser http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

Answer (score 8):

The clipboard manipulation is not cross-browser. For cross-browser solution you need flash.

Look at this library https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard

You can use ZeroClipboard like this:

```
<button id="my-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy me!">Copy to Clipboard</button>
<script>
    var clip = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById('my-button'));
</script>
```

When you click on the button the text `Copy me!` will be put into the clipboard.

For further instructions check the library's API https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md

Comment: And what if cb is not a concern? I want a non-flash solution on Chrome only, since my place of employment is smart enough to only use the best.

Comment: Was just working on a legacy system that had this implemented. It only seems to works on IE as I believe flash is being deprecated in Chrome and other browsers.

Answer (score 7):

I think the window.clipboardData is IE only. Accessing the clipboard is a security concern, and thus cannot be done easily in FF or Chrome.

Please see this thread: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

See [the documentation for `clipboardData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms535220(v=vs.85).aspx), specifically the section that reads:

> There are no standards that apply here.

You are using proprietary Microsoft gubbins, so it shouldn't be expected to work on other browsers.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome) for cross-browser techniques to access the clipboard.

There is [a draft of a standard for accessing the clipboard](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html) but I'm not aware of any implementations of it in the wild (and [canIuse doesn't know of any either](http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboard)).

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem with Chrome and other browsers recently. However, recently, I found this code works in a contenteditable field in certain browsers:

```
clipboard = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;
clipboard.setData('text/plain', plainData);
clipboard.setData('text/html', htmlData);
```

NOTE: e in this case is the copy and/or cut event. This event fires and is retrievable in an `onCopy()` or `onCut()` action.

This code is confirmed to work in the latest versions of the following browsers:

- Chrome (PCs/Macs and Android)
- Android 4.4+ WebView (as long as you update from the Play Store) -> good news for Android Devs
- Firefox
- Safari (Mac only)

Internet Explorer seems to work with `window.clipboardData.setData` instead, but keep in mind that the IE clipboard will only accept `'text'` and `'url'` data.

While the following browsers can access the system clipboard object, these are unable to set data into the clipboard using `clipboard.setData`:

- MS Edge

  - gives an `UntrustedDragDrop` object into the clipboard instead...
  - also, setData returns true... when it doesn't work. setData returns undefined in all other browsers
- Android WebView -> below 4.4
- iOS Safari and WebView - yay iOS!

Answer (score 0):

I found that these do not work in Chrome or FF:

type="hidden"

```
<input id="e" type="hidden" value="my text to copy to clipboard" />
```

style="display:none;"

```
<input id="e" type="text" style="display:none;" value="my text to copy to clipboard" />
```

---

trick the browser with this

style="position: absolute; top: -30;"

```
<input id="e" type="text" style="position: absolute; top: -30;" value="my text" />
```