# How would I implement 'copy url to clipboard' from a link or button using javascript or dojo without flash

Tags: javascript, dojo

I got stucked in implementing this feature on my web application. All the other possibilities are mostly by using flash content. Could someone explain how I can achieve it by using plain javascript or by Dojo.

Comment: Which browsers would you like to support?

Comment: Flash is commonly used because you cannot use JavaScript to reliably copy to the users clipboard; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460210/copy-to-clipboard-not-working-in-ff-chrome

Comment: @SlawomirDemichowicz I am looking for cross browser solution. I come to know that there is a solution in IE

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127040/copy-put-text-on-the-clipboard-with-firefox-safari-and-chrome?

Comment: @Raghuram there is now a better way. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been working on the exact same issue for a while. For me flash isn't a viable solution so I came up with this simple work around:

`<button onclick="prompt('Press Ctrl + C, then Enter to copy to clipboard','copy me')">Click to Copy</button>`

It requires some extra work on the users end but at least it doesn't require flash or external libraries.

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYFJf/)

Comment: Thanks @LcLk. Although it does not manipulate clipboard data. I achieved my functionality to display data that users can copy to their clip board.

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to implement the same feature. Ended up using https://clipboardjs.com.

```
new Clipboard('.btn', {
  text: function() {
    return window.location.href;
  }
});
```

Works well

Answer (score 3):

Html

```
<a class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Copy profile Link" onclick="copy_to_clipboard('<%=public_profile_url(user.public_id)%>')">
<i class="fa fa-copy"></i>
```

Css

```
#url_public_id{
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
function copy_to_clipboard(link) {
    $("#url_public_id").show()
    var Url = document.getElementById("url_public_id");
    Url.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $("#url_public_id").hide()
    alert("Copied URL ");
}
```

Comment: `document.execCommand()` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time, but this now works:

```js
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Which copies the currently selected text to the clipboard. If you want to copy a specific text using javascript, you would have to create a fake input element in the DOM, then do the following

```js
let element = document.getElementById('yourID');
element.value = 'yourText';
element.select();
element.setSelectionRange(0, element.value.length);
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Comment: Not only is `document.execCommand()` now deprecated, but a more complete solution using it was posted all the way back in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

check my code it's working

```
static getFileUrl(id){
    var url=new URL("http://localhost:3000/FileUrl")
    url.searchParams.append('id',id)
    return url.href
}
static copyFileUrl(id){
    copy(this.getFileUrl(id))
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).